# Adding elements to dropdownlist through javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, drop-down-menu

Am unable to add elements to a dropdown list via Javascript.

The below piece of code works in IE and Chrome, but not in firefox.

```
ddlId.add(new Option("",0));
```

In firefox, I keep getting an 'Not enough arguments' exception. Any idea on how to resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try {
    ddlId.add(new Option("",0), null);  // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
} catch(ex) {
    ddlId.add(new Option("",0));    // IE only
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm. The idea is, roughly, to go to the [Mozilla Developer Center page for `select.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/select.add) and have a look at the method signature ;-)

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> select.add(newOption, existingOption);
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *newOption*
>  An HTMLOptionElement to add to the options collection.
>
> *existingOption*
>  An existing HTMLOptionElement within the
>   collection used as a reference point
>   for inserting the new element; the new
>   element being inserted before the
>   referenced element in the collection. 
>   If this parameter is null, the new
>   element is appended to the end of the
>   collection.

Comment: Thanks! Will remember to check out there in case of any firefox related JS issues!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var opt = document.createElement("option");
  var ddlPopulate=document.getElementById("<%=ddlPopulate.ClientId %>");
opt.text="firstElement";
  opt.value="1";
  ddlPopulate.options.add (opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **select** element has as its children an **options** array. You add or remove options as you would using standard array methods.